# React Component Initial State with Props not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component called FeatureBuilds which receives an array of builds(objects) from the parent component as props.

The problem is if I directly access the page which displays the Feature builds, the builds are not listed. Same is the case If I reload the page which displays the Feature builds.

**Seems like the FeatureBuilds components get mounted first, while Parent component is still fetching the data, so props don't have the initial data to display in FeatureBuilds component.**

But If I first access some other page and then come to FeatureBuilds page, it works properly.

Also I see `componentWillMount` in the `FeatureBuilds` component logs before data is getting fetched in parent component.

**Note : The project is running React 16.3 so can't use React hooks.**

**FeatureBuilds Component**

```js
export default class FeatureBuilds extends Component {
  state = {
    featureBuilds: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({featureBuilds: this.props.builds.slice(0,10)})
    console.log('FeatureBuilds  : componentWillMount :: ' + this.state.featureBuilds);
  }

  onClickInstall = val => {
    this.props.onClickInstall(val);
  };

  onPageChange = (page) => {
    console.log('FeatureBuilds : onPageChange :: ' + page);
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * 10
    const builds = this.props.builds.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 10);
    this.setState({featureBuilds: builds})
  }
  
  getFeatureBuildsList() {
    return this.state.featureBuilds.map(val => (
      <div key={val.Key}>
        <Card
          key={val.Key}
          extra={
            <a onClick={() => this.onClickInstall(val)}>
              <span style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#00B14F' }}>
                Install
              </span>
            </a>
          }
          title={
            <span
              style={{
                whiteSpace: 'pre-line',
                fontSize: '14px',
                wordBreak: 'break-word',
              }}
            >
              {val.Key}
            </span>
          }
          type="inner"
          style={{
            marginTop: 8,
          }}
          bodyStyle={{ padding: '10px 20px 10px' }}
        >
          {
            <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>
              {moment(val.LastModified).format('DD/MM/YYYY | HH:mm')}
            </span>
          }
        </Card>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card
        title="Feature builds"
        bordered={false}
        bodyStyle={{ padding: '0px' }}
      >
        <p
          style={{
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: 500,
          }}
        />
        {this.getFeatureBuildsList()}
      </Card>
      <br/>
      <Pagination  onChange={this.onPageChange} total={this.props.builds.length} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FeatureBuilds.propTypes = {
  builds: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      Key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      LastModified: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
  onClickInstall: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

**App Component**

```js
export default class Apps extends Component {
  changeApp = activeKey => {
    this.props.onAppChange(activeKey);
  };

  onPageChange = (page) => {
    console.log('App Component : onPageChange :: ' + page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div key="apps">
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={this.changeApp}>
          <Tabs.TabPane key="a" tab="A">
            <BetaBuilds
              onClickInstall={this.props.onClickInstall}
              builds={this.props.betaBuilds}
            />
            <br />
            <FeatureBuilds
              onClickInstall={this.props.onClickInstall}
              builds={this.props.featureBuilds}
              onPageChange={this.props.onPageChange}
            />
          </Tabs.TabPane>

          <Tabs.TabPane key="b" tab="B">
            <BetaBuilds
              onClickInstall={this.props.onClickInstall}
              builds={this.props.betaBuilds}
            />
            <br />
            <FeatureBuilds
              onClickInstall={this.props.onClickInstall}
              builds={this.props.featureBuilds}
              onPageChange={this.props.onPageChange}
            />
          </Tabs.TabPane>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home Component**

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    contentA: [],
    contentB: [],
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.getAllBuilds(this.state.selectedApp);
    // in the getAllBuilds state contentA and contentB are set
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Apps
          betaBuilds={this.state.contentB}
          featureBuilds={this.state.contentA}
          onAppChange={this.changeApp}
          onClickInstall={this.clickInstallHandler}
          onPageChange={this.onPageChange}
        />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data fetcher (`getAllBuilds`) is an async function so components will render (and so the `componentWillMount` and the `setState` will call with an empty array) while the fetch is still getting the data, and after a while the data is ready you can use it, so you should call the `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` function not in `componentWillMount`:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.builds !== this.props.builds)
    this.setState({featureBuilds: this.props.builds.slice(0,10)});
}
```